# create random mines for a minesweeper game

Tags: java, minesweeper

```
 JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[20][20];
public void mines(){
    ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> y = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int a=0;a<20;a++){
        x.add(a);
        y.add(a);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
    int random_x = x.get(new Random().nextInt(x.size()));
    int random_y = y.get(new Random().nextInt(y.size()));
    x.remove(random_x);
    y.remove(random_y);
    buttons[random_x][random_y].setText("X");
    }  
}
```

I Want to create random mines for a minesweeper game..can anyone tell what I am doing wrong ?If i run the program it won't show me 30 random mines

Comment: Isn't this an NPE? Unless the values in `buttons` are initialised somewhere.

Comment: Why are you treating x and y separately? Surely you want to remove 30 random pairs, not 30 random x coordinates and 30 random y coordinates.

Comment: they are initialised somewhere

Comment: It's easier for me to understand if i take them separately..Should this be the problem?

Comment: The heck if I know -- you're not telling us what problems you might be having, and not showing adequate code. Better to tell and show all errors, exceptions, misbehaviors, and to post a full [mcve].

Comment: I think you're using the wrong overload of `remove`, but I'm not really sure what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method:

```
public static void mines(JButton[][] buttons)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int mineCount = 0;
    while (mineCount < 30)
    {
        int randomInteger = (int) (rand.nextDouble() * buttons.length);
        int randomInteger2 = (int) (rand.nextDouble() * buttons[0].length);
        if (buttons[randomInteger][randomInteger2].getText().equals("X"))
            continue;
        else
        {
            buttons[randomInteger][randomInteger2].setText("X");
            mineCount++;
        }
    }

}
```

`.nextDouble()` method returns a Double value less than 1.0. But we need a random integer between 0 and 19(which is `buttons.length`-1).

So we multiply this random double value with the size of the button list, which is 20, and we cast it to int. So we can get values between 0 and 19.

Difference between `buttons.length` and `buttons[0].length` is, with the first one you get the length of first dimension(it's a two dimension array, as you know) and the second one gives the length of the second dimension. So you get the number dynamically and multiply with the random number, to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.

You can use this method with any size of two dimensional buttons array, it will work. But warning, if you use an array which has less than 30 buttons, while loop will continue forever, as you can't get 30 mines :)

One way to improve this method would be parameterizing mineCount, so you can change the method like `public static void mines(JButton[][] buttons, int mineCount)` so you can set mine count on method call.

Comment: I did update the code 2 times. Are you sure you did try the last one? And, I don't think this doesn't work, what error you get?

Comment: cannot find method length()..variable buttons of type JButtons[][]

Comment: Now it shows no errors..but it still doesn't change the text of buttons into X..do i have to call this method somewhere?

Comment: Of course! If you don't call this method, how can you expect a change? Call the method, with `buttons` argument

Comment: Please create and post an actual answer -- an answer that explains problems and offers an explanation of a solution, not just "try this" and a code dump.

Comment: @BaiRadule ; ) Is there any line that you don't understand? If so, I can add comments into the code.

Comment: (rand.nextDouble() * buttons.length); i don't understand what is this exatcly doing and this (rand.nextDouble() * buttons[0].length);

Answer (score 2):

You have chosen an unusual model for holding information on where mines are located. While you will likely resolve the immediate problem through some judicious debugging I expect it will cause you further problems down the track.

I would suggest changing your model to be something more direct such as:

```
class Cell {
    private final JButton button = new JButton();
    private boolean mine = false;
    private boolean hidden = true;

    public Cell() {
        button.setText(" ");
    }

    public void setMine() {
        assert hidden;
        mine = true;
    }

    public boolean hasMine() {
        return mine;
    }

    public void reveal() {
        hidden = false;
        button.setText(mine ? "X" : "-");
    }

    public boolean isHidden() {
        return hidden;
    }
}

class Field {
    public static final int SIZE = 20;

    private final Cell[][] cells = new Cell[SIZE][SIZE];

    public Field(int minesToAdd) {
        for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; ++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < SIZE; y++) {
                cells[x][y] = new Cell();
            }
        }
        Random random = new Random();
        while (minesToAdd > 0) {
            Cell cell = cells[random.nextInt(SIZE)][random.nextInt(SIZE)];
            if (!cell.hasMine()) {
                cell.setMine();
                minesToAdd--;
            }
        }
    }

    public JPanel getButtonPanel() {
        ....
    }
}
```

I believe that would make your intention clearer. There are a few issues with this such as the tight link between the model and presentation (JButton) but that's entirely fixable with various design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

This here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    int random_x = x.get(new Random().nextInt(x.size()));
    int random_y = y.get(new Random().nextInt(y.size()));
    x.remove(random_x);
    y.remove(random_y);
....
```

is going to generate a **IndexOutOfBoundsException** some when....

Your List have 20 elements and you are removing 30 times element from it...

Comment: Why is that?..in the console it doesnt say anything about IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: hmmm...maybe becouse i have it to take 30 mines..but in the arraylist of x and y i have only 20 ints and every time it takes one it eliminates it..so at some point the arraylist will be empty?

Answer (score 0):

Your random coordinates may be larger than your grid size. If the size of x is 20, and your random_x is also 20, you will have an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Change it to:

```
int random_x = x.get(new Random().nextInt(x.size() - 1));
int random_y = y.get(new Random().nextInt(y.size() - 1));
```

Which will give you a random number between 0 and 19, if the size is 20.

Additionally, because your List is of type `Integer`, the `x.remove(random_x)` call is interpreting it as the index in the list, not the object itself.

To fix this, use an `Integer`, not an `int` when calling `remove()`. Such as:

```
x.remove(Integer.valueOf(random_x));
```

---

Edit:
To further improve/fix the random generator, change it to:

```
int random_x = x.get(new Random().nextInt(x.size() == 1 ? 1 : x.size() - 1));
```

---

When tested with the following snippet:

```
Test t = new Test();
t.mines();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        if ("X".equals(t.buttons[i][j].getText())) {
            System.out.println("x:" + i + ", y:" + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Gives the output:
x:0, y:18
x:1, y:5
x:2, y:1
x:3, y:3
x:4, y:9
x:5, y:15
x:6, y:14
x:7, y:10
x:8, y:8
x:9, y:11
x:10, y:16
x:11, y:17
x:12, y:0
x:13, y:7
x:14, y:4
x:15, y:12
x:16, y:2
x:17, y:6
x:18, y:13
x:19, y:19

Comment: i tried still doesn't change the text of the buttons into X so i guess it;s not working

Comment: @BaiRadule If the text doesn't change, then I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: i see..interesting thing with removing the value..Thanks!

Comment: This seems a little it more complicated for me ,i like Sailbot code much more,considering that i just started learning java a few days ago..Thank You for pointing out what was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
int x = 20;
int y = 20;
JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[x][y];

public void mines(){
    int mines = 30;
    Random rand = new Random()
    while(mines>0){
        int random_x = rand.nextInt(x);
        int random_y = rand.nextInt(y);
        if(buttons[random_x][random_y]!=null){
            buttons[random_x][random_y] = new Button();
            buttons[random_x][random_y].setText("X")
            mines--;
        }  
    }
}
```